# How do I detect (probable) faulty hardware?

Tags: freeze, hardware-failure

For a long time now I've been using Razer Game booster as a tool to keep my PC from freezing. The way it works is if the "boosted" mode is activated, my PC won't freeze on it's own. Freeze as in nothing is responding and I have to hard restart.

I've been suspecting some software conflicts with background programs which game booster would turn off in it's boosted mode. But today I installed Linux Mint as dual boot, and after some time it froze just like my windows 7 would.

That leads me to conclusion that I probably have some faulty hardware, and I have no idea how to fix this problem.

SYSTEM SPECS:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1
AMD Athlon 64 X2 4200+
4,00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 315MHz
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. M68M-S2P - motherboard
512MB NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GTX/9800 GTX+

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is way too broad a topic. So many things can be going on or wrong. There will likely be a lot of debate about what you should do or try, most of which probably won't help because of just guessing. I suggest you do some basic diagnostics so you have more concise data to share. Then update your question with a specific question we can answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add in your question, the specs of your system. Also, there is no program that can really prevent your system from freezing as it depends on what is actually causing it. I think you misunderstood of what your program does, and that is it prevents other software from causing your system to freeze because of CPU load or utilizing all of your ram. In no way could it stop hardware, drivers, corrupt files(specifically system files) etc from freezing your system.

Anyways to answer how you can detect if you have faulty hardware, you can look at windows event viewer and in the hardware view, it should tell you if it detected errors with your hardware. To thoroughly test if your hard drive has bad sectors which can cause the freezing, you can run chkdsk from the command prompt as so `chkdsk /F`  also you can check to see if you have any corrupt system files which is not a hardware problem but can also cause the freeze from command prompt `SFC /SCANNOW`

While windows would more likely detect faulty ram cards, if you have a windows disc, boot from the windows disc, select repair computer, it will bring up a window where you can perform some diagnostics like doing a memory check which will check your ram cards to see if they are faulty.